# COM registration failed because needs administrator permissions

Tags: windows-7, com, visual-studio-2005, regasm

I am getting errors while registering a COM component. From command line I am getting the following error

> RegAsm : error RA0000 : An error occurred while writing the
>   registration information to the registry. Administrator permissions
>   are needed to use the selected options. Use an administrator command
>   prompt to complete these tasks.

From the Visual Studio registration, I am getting the error

> error MSB3216: Cannot register assembly "xxxxxxx.dll" - access
>   denied. Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit with all the updates installed and I have disabled UAC. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Seems you've not actually disabled UAC.  Run regasm.exe from an elevated command prompt like the message says.  If you want to do it from VS then you need to elevated it as well.  Right-click the shortcut and click "Run as administrator".

Comment: I have done that as well. This is baffling.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/2d1a851b-b555-49d7-9cce-cdafea965dfb/ gives me a hint that its a limitation of VS2005 msbuild.

Comment: You likely need to "run as administrator" - either start `cmd` "as administrator" or craft a .cmd file with the command you want to run and run that "as administrator".

Comment: Does the source project have been compiled with "Register for COM Interop" option checked?

Comment: did You ever solved it?